# Asp.NET Identity with Webforms and Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, webforms, asp.net-identity

Is it possible to use **Microsoft Identity** with an existing **WebForms** application using an **Oracle** database?
I'm targeting the **.NET Framework 4.5**, and using the standard "WebForms" template within **Visual Studio 2013**, with **Individual User Account** authentication, so I already have all the References, just don't know how to use them.

I couldn't find any good resource about using that with Oracle and Webforms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AspNet.Identity.Oracle for ASP.NET Identity 2.0 with ODP.NET
Refer below articles:

https://github.com/arichika/AspNet.Identity.Oracle

Comment: Thank you but I need something more stable, since this is a company project :)